# NullPointer Exception in Cordova 3.5 android File Plugin

Tags: java, javascript, cordova, cordova-3

I recently upgraded my cordova app from v2.9 to v3.5. I added the needed plugins through command line and did a cordova build of my app. I am getting a Nullpointer Exception when I read/write a file through file plugin. Below is the stack trace:

```
07-08 18:58:40.750: W/System.err(6670): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 18:58:40.750: W/System.err(6670):     at org.apache.cordova.file.LocalFilesystem.filesystemPathForURL(LocalFilesystem.java:67)
07-08 18:58:40.750: W/System.err(6670):     at org.apache.cordova.file.LocalFilesystem.getFileForLocalURL(LocalFilesystem.java:189)
07-08 18:58:40.750: W/System.err(6670):     at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.getFile(FileUtils.java:749)
07-08 18:58:40.760: W/System.err(6670):     at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.access$5(FileUtils.java:742)
07-08 18:58:40.760: W/System.err(6670):     at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils$16.run(FileUtils.java:397)
07-08 18:58:40.760: W/System.err(6670):     at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils$23.run(FileUtils.java:525)
07-08 18:58:40.760: W/System.err(6670):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-08 18:58:40.760: W/System.err(6670):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-08 18:58:40.760: W/System.err(6670):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I need some immediate help here!!

**Nullpointer Exception solved, but need help in file access**

I would like to know, what should be the pattern of the url for a file access from the app's private package. In cordova 2.9, I was accessing it as `/data/data/com.myapp.android/abc.txt` from the Javascript. May I know what is the format of the url now in cordova 3.5?

Comment: You should post some code too, so that others could figure out the problem.

Comment: The bug I guess is in the file plugin. Which code should I post?

Comment: Where are you storing files? in SD card or internal storage or somewhere else?

Comment: in the private package of the app, which is something like `/data/data/com.myapp.android`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve it by storing my app files in `/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp.android/` folder. This location will be private to my app, and will be cleared when the app is uninstalled.

Now, I can read/write files from javascript using cordova's File plugin, and a file path will be like: `Android/data/com.myapp.android/abc.txt`. Since File plugin considers `Compatibility` as the default value for preference `AndroidPersistentFileLocation` in config.xml, the persistent file store will be returned as `/mnt/sdcard` (if mounted), which is by default in Android.

**Reference:** [Google groups link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/python-android/hLSCBdFjNWI/72pNpik69yMJ)

Comment: Good You got an answer. Now you can award your bounty to your self ;)

Comment: ha ha..but unfortunately SO does not allow that

Answer (score 5):

You need to add one of the following to your config.xml file

`<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />`

`<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />`

[Check More details on this page](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md#android-quirks) It says

> If your application has previously been shipped to users, using an
>   older (pre- 1.0) version of this plugin, and has stored files in the
>   persistent filesystem, then you should set the preference to
>   "Compatibility". Switching the location to "Internal" would mean that
>   existing users who upgrade their application may be unable to access
>   their previously-stored files, depending on their device.

**EDTT**

You can try it this way,

`cdvfile:///data/data/com.myapp.android`

[Check out](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md#upgrading-notes)

Comment: I will try this and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: I used the setting as Internal in config.xml, but this did not work.

Comment: @Rajesh Did you re-build your app? And are you getting same NPE?

Comment: I am using eclipse and that takes care of the build process.

Comment: @Rajesh You should do Clean & Build your self and try again.

Comment: Yes i did clean and build...that did not help. I am going to update the question with the progress

Comment: No that did not work. It threw an illegal character exception because of `:` in `cdvfile://`. I guess the file url cannot have any scheme.

Answer (score 2):

try using this

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(URI, function(f){
    var filePath = f.fullPath;
}
```

where URI would be /data/data/com.myapp.android/abc.txt or just abc.txt

Comment: that would give me a `FileEntry` object. How can I write to a file using the file entry object if the file does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add android file location. Add this to your config.xml

preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal"

This will resolve the problem